# Enterprise library xml

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I've just notice in my bin/Release folder some xml files that i don't really want to see there. Any idea why they are there and how to get rid of them?

> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.xml
>
> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.xml

Comment: They look like the intellisense files for Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll and Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.dll - do you perhaps have those xml files in your project tree? (solution explorer)

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm not sure i understand your question. I'm referencing EntLib from the GAC and i don't have those xml anywhere in my Sln.

Comment: You answered the question fine; the other option was you were referencing them inside the project tree (rather than the GAC), with the files marked to copy during build. That at least gives us the necessary context.

Answer (score 1):

These files are the xml comments from the Enterprise library, VS.Net uses then for intellisense. You do not have to deploy them with your solution.

Comment: Thanks Peer, I know that i don't have to deploy them. My deployment process is: Copy paste from release to destination. I just don't want to have them in my bin - if possible. And I don't want any post build events.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the files by editing the project file to add the         `<AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>` tag and supplying the file extensions you wish to **include**.

For me MSBuild is defaulting that to

```
AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions = 
            .pdb;
            .xml
```

So to remove the XML files set the following in the project file to only include .pdb files and (implicitly) exclude .xml:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
        .pdb
    </AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions> 
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify this via the command line:

MsBuild.exe build.file /p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=none